# Как реализовать self injection в Spring для бина со scope prototype?

Tags: java, spring

Для singleton-бинов это можно сделать, например, так:

```
@Component
public class MySingletonBean {
    @Autowired
    private MySingletonBean mBean;
    
    //some logic...
}
```

В случае с prototype это решение не сработает по понятным причинам. Как в таком случае в бине получить ссылку на самого себя (а точнее на то, что возвращает спринг-контейнер, то есть это может быть и прокси-объект с какой-то дополнительной логикой)?

Comment: Вот же! https://www.baeldung.com/spring-inject-prototype-bean-into-singleton

Comment: По каким причинам, непонятно.

Comment: @RomanC например при AOP'е - если вызвать из одного public-метода другой public-метод, к которому привязан аспект, то аспект не выполнится в случае прямого вызова, потому что он пойдёт через неявную ссылку this. А в случае, если мы вызовем его через ссылку на себя же, которую нам предоставит Spring - аспект выполнится, потому что Spring завернёт его в Proxy с аспектом.